# I dont understand why my code isnt working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to the value of a button once it is clicked. But for some reason, the console keeps giving me an error saying buttonValue.addEventListener is not a function!!!
The following is my code:

```
var buttonValue = document.querySelector('.btn').value

buttonValue.addEventListener('click', function(){
  console.log(buttonValue);
});

and here is my HTML code!:

<div>
<button class='btn' value="1">1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: because an input value is a string and a string does not have addEventListener. You should be binding the event listener to the button, not the value.

Comment: You should not add an event listener to `.value` but to the button itself. Also, make sure the JS code executes after the HTML is ready.

Comment: @epascarello could you please by using code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:
you should have placed add event listener on the element, not the value of the element

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.btn')

buttonValue.addEventListener('click', function(){
  console.log(button.value);
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCHHHH!!!!!!!!!!! IT TOOK ME FOREVER TO FIGURE THIS OUT! YOU ARE THE BEST!!!:))))))

Comment: No problem. By the way would you mind marking this as the answer? Thanks